# Is it possible to adapt or modify a bluetooth dongle to be used to connect any device other then what it came with?

Tags: bluetooth

So out of curiousity is there a way to use any bluetooth dongle as a reciever so i can connect say my android phone to my pc? Im not great with computers yet but im new only been toying around for about a year but i pick up anything fairly quick so if anyone has any advise or maybe even knows of a program/tutorial on how to do so if its even possible I'd really appreciated thanks

Comment: What does the dongle show up as when connected (like in `lsusb` or in Device Manager devmgmt.msc)? Is it really a Bluetooth dongle and not a custom 2.4 GHz dongle?

Comment: It depends if the dongle is actually bluetooth in the first place. Just because it *looks* like a bluetooth dongle does not mean it uses the same protocol at all. If it came with a keyboard or mouse it is entirely possible that it uses something else entirely, probably some in-house radio transmission protocol.

Answer (score 1):

If it's really a Bluetooth dongle, it can already do that without any additional steps.

If it can't do that out of the box, it's not a Bluetooth dongle, but a proprietary one which most likely works on the same 2.4 GHz band as Bluetooth. It doesn't make it Bluetooth-compatible though - a lot of stuff uses 2.4 GHz, from WiFi to microwave ovens.

Bluetooth-enabled devices usually don't come with dongles. If you got one, it's most likely not Bluetooth.

Comment: It seems you answered the question 11 seconds after it was closed. Apparently the stoat can slip through a closing door. :D